# How to test if a vertex has been deleted in a polyhedron?

Tags: cgal

Specially, the problem i am trying to solve is deleting points that are very close together in a closed polyhedron.

I start first by collecting all the halfedges that are very short in distance (which implies that two points are very close together)

After which i go through the list of halfedges and start deleting the vertices using "erase_center_vertex".

The problem that comes is such that I do not know how to test if a vertex has already been deleted .. so that if some other halfedges references it again and tries to delete it, an error is prompted..

i tried the following....

if ( my_halfedge != Halfedge_handle() ) erase_center_vertex(my_halfedge);

if ( my_halfedge->vertex() != vertex_handle() ) erase_center_vertex(my_halfedge);

In all case, although the vertex is already deleted from the polyhedron, but somehow the halfedge pointing to it still exist, and pointing to a valid vertex (which should have been deleted).

Question : How to test if a vertex or halfedge has been removed?

Comment: If you delete a vertex, the resulting polyhedron will have new edges that weren’t there before. Are you deleting multiple vertices at the same time? Or are you deleting one and then testing to see if you need to delete another?

Comment: So this is the general algo.. 1. Collect all edges that needs to be deleted .... 2. delete the first one .... 3. Check if second edge is still valid and present, if so then delete... 4. repeat

Comment: The problem i am facing is .. how to test if an edge is still part of the polyhedron? or has it already been deleted?

Comment: How would an edge become invalid for deletion between the time that you mark it for deletion and the time that you delete it?

Comment: suppose there are 3 points, A,B,C that are very close together... There are two edges , E1 (A->B)  and E2 (C->B) that are earmarked for deletion. using the function "erase_center_vertex(E1), we deleted vertex B. At this point, E2 will also be deleted along with it. E2 is not connected to the polyhedron anymore. When we try to delete E2, an error will pop up. .... So the question remains... how do I know if E2 is still existing and connected to the polyhedron?

Comment: It’s unclear what the function `erase_center_vertex(E1)` does. If you’re deleting a vertex, why are you passing an edge to the function?

Comment: No, its quite clear what erase_center_vertex does... you can read up at https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedron__3.html#a2d08e7da8a337ed90b0db2e9a37d21c6

Comment: The reason why an edge is passed instead of an vertex is irrelevant, since there is a 1-to-1 relationship between an half_edge and a vertex....  Beside, this is how the function is implemented, based on the CGAL API .... https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedron__3.html#a2d08e7da8a337ed90b0db2e9a37d21c6

Comment: I see now. The problem may be in how you are iterating over your edges... how are you doing that?

Comment: There are many ways of avoiding this situation, I agree. The exact method of the algorithm is not important. The question I wish to have an answer to, is this.. If you were to store a vertex/halfedge/facet variable.. and subsequently it got deleted from the polyhedron, are you able to tell from the variable that it has been deleted?